# Recommend way to setup a terminal program to run in the background on boot?

Tags: command-line, administration

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 Server edition.  Currently I boot up the server, log in, run the application "screen", run an existing terminal program to do some work, and then use screen to lock the computer while keeping the program running.  I unlock screen from time to time to check how work is progressing throughout the week.  The output of the terminal program is a dashboard-like display in the terminal.  The program takes up the whole terminal display.  Values on the terminal display are overwritten as they are updated.

The terminal program in question is an existing application.  Modifying its source code is currently out of scope.

What I'd like to do is set up the system to do the following:

On boot of the computer, the terminal program in question would run automatically in the background.  I'd like to then be able to log in from time to time and connect to the terminal program so that I could view the dashboard in the terminal interface to check how work is progressing.

There seems to be a number of different ways in a Linux OS such as Ubuntu 11.10 Server Edition to make something like this happen.

What's the recommended setup or recommended technologies to use to make the above happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems that question 814 only addresses one small part... how to start a program on boot. Upstart, the recommendation to 814, seems to assume in the examples that one doesn't need to reconnect to the terminal output.Are you saying that upstart does everything I need?  What chain of technologies are needed to do all that I describe above? (both start the app on boot and log in from time to time and connect to dashboard output in a terminal display)